# If this tech in The Last Jedi was new, how did the Resistance get detailed schematics of it?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, plot-device

In *The Last Jedi* some key new technology is assumed to be the reason why:

> The First Order can now track ships through hyperspace without the use of a tracking beacon.

Not long after this, several characters come up with a plan for how to disable this tech. As part of their discussion holographic schematics showing both the appearance and location of this tech are shown.

If this tech was new how did the Resistance have access to the schematics showing both what it looked like and where it was physically located?

Comment: The tech they showed was the "active tracker" not the hyperspace tracking algorithm or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: They assumed it was based on the same tech and possibly even the same tech. For all they knew it was different but it was the best plan they had

Comment: @Edlothiad And? The point is they identified something that they needed to destroy on the FO ship, yet already had access to detailed schematics showing both where it was and what it looked like. My question was asking how they got hold of those schematics in the first place and how they determined which "thing" out of the millions of components in that ship was the thing that they needed to destroy.

Comment: The schematics weren't for anything knew. That's the point I'm making. I'm not attempting to answer the entirety of your question, merely making possible points of consideration, hence the comment, not the answer.

Comment: 1 - This technology already appears in rogue one 2- 
Finn was in the order a long time 3- Contraband of weapons that is reflected in the film. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Edlothiad The schematics were pretty obviously of the Supremacy, the FO ship containing the tracker, tech, whatever you want to call it. I guess the Resistance may have obtained schematics for that ship through spies or other means. However, an area of that ship is highlighted in red and it is heavily implied that this is the area of the ship that contains the tracker; the same area that Finn and Rose end-up at later in the movie just before they're captured. How did they know that was the thing on the ship that they needed to destroy?

Comment: I think Finn says something along the lines of he used to mop the floor of that room. Even if they didn't have schematics he'd know where to look and they could have just plugged the coords into a computer to create the fancy projection. The tech in the image is also probably old so I think they would have had schematics for that.

Comment: @Gawey This tech does not "appear" in Rogue One, it is mentioned as a project name in a throwaway line. Given everyone's surprise when the tracking technique is assumed/revealed it is pretty obvious that it has never been used to track any Rebel/Resistance craft prior to this point in the series.

Comment: Sorry to tell you that most of the projects that appear are related to things that end up happening or that have happened. Like the "black saber".

Comment: @Gawey I'm not arguing the tech doesn't exist: it's shown in the movie. The point is that the movie heavily implies that this particular tech has never been used before this point.

Comment: You’re not understanding what I’m saying. The thing they highlight is an active tracker, which R&F suggest is a currently existing technology. The way they do hyperspace tracking is an extension of the _existing_ technology that they highlight. God knows how they got the schematics to the supremacy, but once they had, Finn knew what he was looking for, because he’d seen it before.

Comment: @Edlothiad I see where you're coming from now.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the schematics of the tracker they show was of an old tracker, the normal type, not the active tracker (light speed one). However, Finn and Rose have a conversation that it must be based on the same technology and so are assuming it is the same tracker though it might not be.

When coming up with the plan a conversation similar to the following takes place (from memory):

> Finn: I used to mop that floor
>   Rose: If you get use there I can disable it

So even if they didn't have the schematics Finn knew where the tracker was so the could have just plugged some coordinates into a computer to get the graphic they showed.

Comment: They call it an Active Tracker

Comment: I don't understand why Rose needed to be there to blow the thing to bits - or were they going to do a nice graceful shutdown of it, leaving it completely intact with the warranty in place?

Comment: @Moo This is explained in the film, if they blew it up or completely disabled it the First Order would notice and just use the device on a different ship. By temporarily disabling it the FO wouldn't notice and it should give them enough time to escape.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot what's to stop the FO from tracking them again using the same technology though? The tracker clearly has a huge range.

Comment: @alexgbelov To track you have to find and track that's why it's called a tracker not a scanner.

Comment: Then again, if they have this on multiple ships and it is new tech, it's again a sign of First Order stupidity to have only one running at a time. I mean, it could be off or malfunction or what not. But you are right of course that this is what the movie tells us.